# Are all polytopes also convex hulls?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polytopes

It seems, at least in the 2-D case, that all polytopes are going to be convex. Does this hold if the dimensions are increased?

Comment: Do you mean regular polygons?

Comment: I'm specifically referring to polytopes created from a combination of half spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular polygons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) are convex whereas [regular polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polytope) may not be. Furthermore, the [Platonic solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) are indeed convex. Maybe you want to read about [convex polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope)?

**edit**: seeing your comment I guess you are really interested in [interesections of halfspaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces)?

Comment: That was it! Thanks!